How do I recreate this Sangoku?
I am trying to recreate this Japanese Sangoku using tkz-euclide:

My attempt so far:
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(-4,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){D}
\tkzDefPoint(60:4){C}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through C](A,B)     
\tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzInterLL(C,X)(A,B)
\tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzInterLC(C,H)(M,B) \tkzGetPoints{E}{F}
\tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C) \tkzGetPoints{I}{i} \tkzDrawCircle[black](I,i)
\tkzDrawSegment(E,F)
\tkzDrawCircle[black,thick](M,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The colours are missing and it's not the same triangle, but that doesn't matter. But I don't know how to place the remaining circles. Can anyone help me? If it helps: The arithmetic mean of the two radii of the lower circles is supposed to be the radius of the upper circle.

It's more a question of mathematics than TEX.

With tkz-euclideonly :
Some explanations :
First, consider the points A,B,O, and the circle with center O passing through A and B. Choose a point C on the circle (-50, -60, -30) see the figures.
Then look for the intersection of the circles of center A and center B passing through C. They intercept the line (AB) at E and F.
Point C is projected onto (AB) at D. The bisectors of angles (BDC) and (CDA) respectively intersect the perpendicular lines at E and F to line (AB). This determines the centers of the blue circles.
Once point G has been obtained, the yellow circle is the inscribed circle of triangle ABG.
Note: there's a relationship between the radius of the yellow circle and the radii of the blue
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,4/0/B,-4/0/A}
\tkzDefPointOnCircle[through = center O angle -50 point B]
\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzInterLC(A,B)(A,C)
 \tkzGetPoints{X}{E}
 \tkzInterLC(A,B)(B,C)
  \tkzGetPoints{F}{X}

\tkzDefPointBy[projection = onto A--B](C)
\tkzGetPoint{D}

\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](E,A)
\tkzGetPoint{X}

\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](F,A)
\tkzGetPoint{Y}
\tkzDefLine[bisector](B,D,C) \tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzDefLine[bisector](C,D,A) \tkzGetPoint{J}

\tkzInterLL(E,X)(D,I) \tkzGetPoint{R}
\tkzInterLL(F,Y)(D,J) \tkzGetPoint{S}
\tkzInterLC(C,D)(O,B) \tkzGetSecondPoint{G}

\tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,G) \tkzGetPoints{K}{T}
\tkzFillCircles[blue!20](R,E S,F)
\tkzFillCircle[yellow](K,T)
 \tkzDrawCircles(O,A R,E S,F K,T)

 \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,G)
 \tkzDrawSegments(A,B C,D)
 \tkzDrawPoints(A,...,F,O,J,S,G)
  \tkzLabelPoints(A,...,F,O,J,S,G)
  \tkzDrawLines(D,I D,J E,X F,Y)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Sangoku with -50 :
Sangoku with -60 : 
Sangoku with -30 : 
With tkz-elements and tkz-euclide. It's possible to use only tkz-euclide but the calculations are not easy. It is also possible to use only TikZ, but this is less comfortable.
The mathematical part is interesting, but it's not the role of tex.exchange ... I can simply point you in the direction of inversions of centers A and B with respect to circles passing through C.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide} 
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=2,color=teal,fill=white]
\directlua{
  z.O      = point :    new (0,0)
  z.B      = point :    new (4,0)
  C.OB     = circle :   new (z.O,z.B)
  z.A      = C.OB :     antipode (z.B)
  z.E      = point :    new (2,0)
  C.AE     = circle :   new (z.A,z.E)
  _,z.C    = intersection (C.OB,C.AE)
  L.AB     = line : new (z.A,z.B)
  z.D      =  L.AB : projection (z.C)
  z.X      = z.E : north (1)
  L.EX     = line : new (z.E,z.X)
  L.DI     = bisector (z.D,z.E,z.C)
  z.R      = intersection (L.EX,L.DI)
  C.BC     = circle :   new (z.B,z.C)
 _,z.F     =  intersection (L.AB,C.BC)
  z.Y      = z.F : north (1)
  L.DJ     = bisector (z.D,z.C,z.F)
  L.FY     = line : new (z.F,z.Y)  
  z.S      = intersection (L.FY,L.DJ)
  L.CD     = line : new (z.C,z.D)
  z.G      = intersection (L.CD,C.OB)
  T.ABG    = triangle : new (z.A,z.B,z.G)
  C.ins    = T.ABG : in_circle () 
  z.K      = C.ins.center
  z.T      = C.ins.through
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
 \tkzGetNodes
 \tkzDrawCircles(O,A R,E S,F K,T)
 \tkzFillCircle[yellow](K,T)
\tkzFillCircles[blue!20](R,E S,F)
 \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,G)
 \tkzDrawSegments(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you! I'm admittedly not very familiar with tkz-elements (I've only worked with tkz-euclid mainly), but I might take a closer look at the documentation if it works better this way.

@JimYe I have posted a solution that uses only tkz-euclide. I'm not impartial, being the author of both packages, but I find tkz-elements more efficient, more elegant and better structured. I forgot to mention that you need to compile with lualatex.

I've taken the liberty of applying a few typo fixes. Feel free to revert.

@Mico No problem  !

The construction is a special case of the Apollonian circle -- for two straight lines and a circle.  Purely for comparison, here is an attempt in Metapost.

To get the desired radius ratio, you need to make the upper triangle a 3-4-5 right angle triangle (apparently), and hence A-B is a diameter.
Compile this source with lualatex:
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef circumcircle(expr A, B, C) = 
  save m; pair m;
  m = whatever * (A - B) rotated 90 shifted 1/2[A,B] 
    = whatever * (B - C) rotated 90 shifted 1/2[B,C];
  fullcircle scaled 2 abs (A - m) shifted m
enddef;
vardef incircle(expr A, B, C) = 
  save a, b, m, t; pair a, b, m, t;
  a = A + unitvector (C-A) + unitvector (B-A);
  b = B + unitvector (A-B) + unitvector (C-B);
  m = whatever[A,a] = whatever [B,b]; t = whatever[A,B];
  t-m = whatever * (B-A) rotated 90;
  fullcircle scaled 2 abs (t-m) shifted m
enddef;
beginfig(1);

  pair A, B, C, D;
  A = origin; B = 300 right;  C = 240 dir angle (4,3);

  path c[];
  c0 = circumcircle(A, B, C);
  c1 = incircle(A, B, C);

  z0 = whatever[A,B]; C - z0 = whatever * (A - B) rotated 90;

  D = (1/16[C,z0] -- 16[C,z0]) intersectionpoint c0;

  z1 = (C--D) shifted (point directiontime(C-D) of c0 of c0 - D)
       intersectionpoint 
       (A--B) shifted (point directiontime(A-B) of c0 of c0 - A);

  z2 = (z1 -- 4[z1,z0]) intersectionpoint subpath (4,8) of c0;
  z3 = whatever[center c0, z2] = whatever[z0, z0 + dir 225];

  c2 = fullcircle scaled 2 abs(z2 - z3) shifted z3;

  z4 = (C--D) shifted (point directiontime(D-C) of c0 of c0 - D)
       intersectionpoint 
       (A--B) shifted (point directiontime(A-B) of c0 of c0 - B);

  z5 = (z4 -- 4[z4,z0]) intersectionpoint subpath (4,8) of c0;
  z6 = whatever[center c0, z5] = whatever[z0, z0 + dir 315];

  c3 = fullcircle scaled 2 abs(z5 - z6) shifted z6;

  fill c1 withcolor (0, 0, 1/2, 0); draw center c1 withpen pencircle scaled 1;
  fill c2 withcolor (1/2, 0, 0, 0); draw center c2 withpen pencircle scaled 1;
  fill c3 withcolor (1/2, 0, 0, 0); draw center c3 withpen pencircle scaled 1;

  draw D--C--B--A--C;
  draw c0;
  draw c1;
  draw c2;
  draw c3;

  dotlabel.lft("$A$", A);
  dotlabel.rt ("$B$", B);
  dotlabel.top("$C$", C);
  dotlabel.bot("$D$", D);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Follow the link at the top for references and tutorials on MP.
